# How to create Eclipse custom java-based new File Wizard based on code templates?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm just starting into some Eclipse (juno) plugin experimentation.  A key part of the plugin I want to create needs to provide the user with the ability to create New java-based classes.  These classes may be 1 of 3 different types.

Is it possible to do this using variation of the NewFileWizard that will use a template for each class type under the hood?

For example, when the user is in the new Custom project they created from the plugin, I'd like them to be able to do a right-click, "New" and be given 3 choices.  Depending on the choice, the wizard will use a corrosponding code template - filling in class name, package name, etc., and then generating the file in the proper project folder.

Please let me know if you need any clarification on what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do this using variation of the NewFileWizard that will use a template for each class type under the hood?

Yes.

You're basically going to have to get the Eclipse source code for the New File Wizard, bring it into an Eclipse plug-in project, and modify it to meet your specific needs.

Comment: interesting - based on this approach, I should be able to create N "new TYPE" wizards.  Would this source code be in with the general eclipse source code, or is it somewhere else?  Thx